# How to write an example function for r package

Tags: r, r-package

I have a package with about 50 functions. Each one has examples. The examples use a .rda data files.
Most of the time the examples are short and work fine.
However I have 10 functions that rely on the prior manipulation by other functions in the package (all in exactly the same way) so the examples become rather long. 
Is there a way of therefore creating a function to provide the data manipulation for these higher order functions so I don't have to clutter up the examples text?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have something like

```
a <- funca()
b <- funcb(a)
c <- funcc(b)
d <- funcd(c)
```

And you need to use `d` for your remaining 10 functions examples, I would just include `d` as an example dataset. You can document the dataset for how it was generated, but in the example for your 10 functions you could just use it as is.

Comment: Theanks @EricWatt. Hopefully not a dumb question but can I document how the dataset was created from existing datasets in the data documentation file? If not where do you put it?

Comment: I follow the `R packages` guide. Check the section `Documenting datasets` here: http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html An example of using `data.R` for documenting data can be found in `ggplot2`: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/data.R

Comment: Also, note the recommendation on that page for putting your code in `data-raw` in an R script. This is nice so that you can reproduce the dataset. Then use documentation in `data.R` so that people can use `help(d)` to know more about your `d` dataset.